# Use a function with an argument of a derived type (F#)

Tags: inheritance, casting, f#, code-reuse, upcasting

I've got a class in my application - for simplicity let's assume it's defined like this:

```
type baseType() =
    member this.A = 5.
```

Also, I've got a lot of functions that take objects of this type as an argument. Moreover, some of them take an array of this type:

```
let myFun (xArr : baseType[]) =
    // ... do something inspirig ;)
```

Now I realized, that it would be nice to have another class which derives from "baseType". e.g.:

```
type inhType() =
    inherit baseType()
    member this.B = 8.
```

However, I can't use the arrays of inherited type with the functions like "myFun"

```
let baseArr = [| baseType() |]
let inhArr = [| inhType() |]

myFun baseArr
myFun inhArr // won't work
```

which would be "nice to have". Is there a simple way to re-use my functions without applying so many changes ?

I guess one of the solution is to map my array using e.g. the function (fun (d : inhType) -> d :> baseType), but I'm wondering if there's anything else could be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to annotate your function as accepting a [flexible type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx).

```
type A() = class end
type B() = inherit A()

let aArr = [| A() |]
let bArr = [| B() |]

// put # before type to indicate it's a flexible type
let f (x : #A[]) = ()

f aArr
f bArr  // works!
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also populate an array of `A` with instances of a subtype, `B`, by using a type annotation:

```
let bArr: A[] = [| B() |]
```

This could be useful for one-off usage or if the function is in a third party library. Another common usage is creating boxed arrays (`obj[]`).

Comment: True, but note that this only works with array literals.  Something like `let bArr : A[] = Array.create 1 (B())` won't work.